# Mount loop restarts unity

Tags: mount

i have a DVD iso file and need to mount it before i can play with totem/vlc. everytime i process this command:

```
mount /path/dvd.iso /mnt/python/ -o loop
```

unity restarts itself (something like 'Unity --replace' command)

how to fix or is this a bug?

Comment: Where do you execute this command? In unity command prompt or in terminal?

Comment: @Anwar, using terminal ..unity command prompt, is it the 'ALT + F2' command?

Comment: I believe this is a bug and as such off-topic on the site. Please follow the bug on launchpad. Best luck

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced the same issue, there is an open bug filed against this problem.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/948972

Comment: thanks for the link. bug status has no update since march ..